# check whether the document present or not in SharePoint before starting download from c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a uri which has the document details. this uri I am getting it from share point . But in some cases if the document is not present document downloading code is giving timeout exception. how can I check whether the document present or not in SharePoint before starting download from c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a HEAD request to the URL to check for the resource. [Example here](https://platinumdogs.me/2014/07/25/checking-sharepoint-resource-url-serviceability-using-javascript-and-html-head/), you will need to port it to C#